# git local repository on different directory error: git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

Tags: git, bash, github, tortoisegit

I am trying to set up origin/master git repository on shared folder. But I keep getting error:

> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

When I try to "push" from my repo to the origin (share folder).

I am using bash and TortoiseGit and gitbash.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have write access right to that folder?

Comment: Any error message in more detailed?

Comment: yes i do. and the folder is not protected with password or anything like that. i get this error after i commit and try to push. i set the destination to Arbitrary URL (with the full PATH of the other repo, i also check "Force Overwrite.."). more of the error: "remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' " -maybe u know any good tutorial about local repo? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should push to a bare repository.

i.e. The directory ends with `.git` and initialized with `git init --bare`.

```
mkdir abc.git
cd abc.git
git init --bare
```

Otherwise, you receive error message `receive.denyCurrentBranch` (non-bare repository).
Pushing to non-bare repository is not recommended.